# Как лучше всего отсрочить прогрузку iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

У меня в сайте стоит `iframe` с ссылкой на другой сайт где лежит форма. В ней есть очень много jquery и в целом она добавляет целых 3 секунды к времени загрузки сайта.

Собственно можно ли отсрочить загрузку этого тега, что бы она грузилась как тег script с атрибутом defer, то есть после прогрузки всего остального документа?

Comment: Используйте $(document).ready(function(){}) или $(window).load(function(){  iframe.src = src; }

Comment: А можете пожалуйста на js без jquery? На сайте у меня его нет и ради строчки кода добавлять jquery мне кажется не особо хорошей идеей

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ // Аналог $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: Преблагодарствую

Comment: Единственное жаль, что в gtmetrix и прочих итоговое время отображается только после прогрузки iframe и оно не поменялось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно тогда не загружать в общем потоке, а добавлять iframe уже после загрузки.

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", append, false ); // после полной загрузки DOM 
или 
window.onload = function(){ append() }; // после загрузки всего контента страницы 
// если нужно выполнить загрузку через несколько секунд 
setTimeout( append, delay );
```